# Retrieve JSON from sql

Tags: json, oracle

My json format in one of the sql columns "jsoncol" in the table "jsontable" is like below.
Kindly help me to get this data using **JSON_QUERY** or **JSON_VALUE**

Please pay attention to the brackets and double quotes in the key value pairs...

```json
{
  "Company": [
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "123"
      },
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Id": 999
    },
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "456"
      },
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Id": 888
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve all the company names using sql query. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT j.name
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.Company[*]'
         COLUMNS(
           name VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.Name'
         )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value CLOB CHECK (value IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES ('{
  "Company": [
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "123"
      },
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Id": 999
    },
    {
      "Info": {
        "Address": "456"
      },
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Id": 888
    }
  ]
}');
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | ABC |
> | XYZ |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e53df65332e2a6b983b9371c77798897)*

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use **JSON_TABLE()** function for this case rather provided the DB version is at least `12.1.0.2` such as

```
SELECT name
  FROM jsontable,
       JSON_TABLE(jsoncol,
                  '$' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH '$."Company"[*]'
                          COLUMNS(name VARCHAR2 PATH '$."Name"')))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=14815e4e271fe1a7c0f7af68b2ba2642)</kbd>